# How can i see the list of apps registered with Eureka server?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to understand 'netflix.eureka.server'. Here is my server code

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServerDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and here is my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

the app is up and running I can see the status using 'http://localhost:8761/actuator/health' and getting {"status":"UP"}

Now here is my client application code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class EurekaClientDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and here is my client application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=EurekaClientDemoApplication
```

and here is my application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Now the client app is also up and running. Now I'm trying to see the clients registered with the eureka server by hitting 'http://localhost:8761/eureka/' but I'm getting page not found exception. Can someone help me understand what am i missing here and how can i see the list of apps registered with my eureka server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figured out how to list all the apps registered with my Eureka server. Here is the URL for the same

http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps